# Why am I getting the "Repaired Records: Format from /xl/styles.xml part" error on this OpenXML Excel Download?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm attempting to add header row formatting to my OpenXML spreadsheet document, and I'm getting the aforementioned error. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with how I'm adding the styling, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The document was opening correctly before I tried adding styling.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
    private void AddStyles()
    {
        stylesPart = doc.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
        stylesPart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts = new Fonts();
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills = new Fills();
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders = new Borders();
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats = new CellFormats();

        stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.Append(new Font()); // normal
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fonts.Append(new Font(new Bold())); // header

        stylesPart.Stylesheet.Fills.Append(new Fill()); //default fill
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.Borders.Append(new Borders()); // default border

        stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Append(new CellFormat() { FormatId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, FontId = 0 });
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.CellFormats.Append(new CellFormat() { FormatId = 1, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0, FontId = 1 });
    }
```

When I open it, it prompts to repair it, and it does so correctly.  However, if I open it in NotePad, I get some crazy stuff.

```
PK    ÄCSM5øiº   %    xl/workbook.xml ¢ (                      Á‚0†_eé]‡F   !€/^õ   æè`­dÊã;1‘«·¯›æû«ÓìFñÄÀ–|
```

Included below is the rest of the code for reference:

```
    public OpenXMLExcelDoc(string sheetName = "Sheet 1")
    {
        ms = new MemoryStream();
        doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

        workBookPart = doc.AddWorkbookPart();
        workBookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        workSheetPart = workBookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        workSheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

        sheets = workBookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
        sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workBookPart.GetIdOfPart(workSheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = sheetName };
        sheetData = workSheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());
        sheets.Append(sheet);

        AddStyles();

        doc.Save();
    }

    public void StartRow()
    {
        row = new Row();
    }
    public void FinishRow()
    {
        sheetData.AppendChild(row);
    }

    public void AddCellData(string data, CellValues dataType, FontStyles style = FontStyles.Normal)
    {
        var newCell = new Cell()
        {
            CellValue = new CellValue(data),
            DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(dataType),
            StyleIndex = Convert.ToUInt32((int)style)
        };

        row.Append(newCell);
    }

    public void AddDataGrid(DataGrid dg)
    {
        StartRow();
        for (var i = 0; i < dg.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            AddCellData(dg.Columns[i].HeaderText, CellValues.String, FontStyles.Header);
        }
        FinishRow();

        for (var i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var gridRow = dg.Items[i];

            StartRow();
            for(var j = 0; j < gridRow.Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                var gridCell = gridRow.Cells[j];
                AddCellData(gridCell.Text, CellValues.String);
            }

            FinishRow();
        }
    }


    public void Finish(string title, HttpResponse Response)
    {            
        doc.Close();

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + title + ".xlsx");

        ms.Position = 0;
        ms.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);

        Response.End();            
    }
```

Comment: The code that you got from notepad (above) was that before or after it was repaired?  Could you please show content for both (before and after repair).

Comment: @tgolisch That's from before, and it's just a portion of it.  After it looks pretty much the same, except that here is a whole lot of instances of "NUL" with a black background.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't understand "why" my code did not work, but the code based on [this post](http://www.dispatchertimer.com/tutorial/how-to-create-an-excel-file-in-net-using-openxml-part-3-add-stylesheet-to-the-spreadsheet/) does.

```
    private void AddStyles()
    {
        stylesPart = workBookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();

        Fonts fonts = new Fonts(
            new Font(),
            new Font(new Bold())
            );

        Fills fills = new Fills(new Fill());
        Borders borders = new Borders(new Border());

        CellFormats cellFormats = new CellFormats(
                new CellFormat(), // default
                new CellFormat { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0 }, // body
                new CellFormat { FontId = 1, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0 } // header
            );

        stylesPart.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet(fonts, fills, borders, cellFormats);
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();
    }
```

Comment: This answer gets the `stylesPart` from `workBookPart`. The first example code does not show code that would associate `stylesPart` with `workBookPart` or `doc`. It also does a `StyleSheet.Save()` after applying the stylesheet definition.